# Only load 5 XML entries with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Right now all the XML nodes are showing on the page. I only want to show 5. 
Then when the user presses "View More", I want 5 more to appear.

Here is my code so far, that is showing all nodes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "feed.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $("#main").html("<div id='box'><div id='title'>Latest from gulfnews.com</div>");
    $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
        $("#box").append("<div class='article'><span class='title'><a target='_blank' href='"+$(this).find("link").text()+"'>"+$(this).find("title").text()+"</a></span><h2>"+$(this).find("title").text()+"</h2></div>");
    });  
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `index` parameter of `.each()`

```
function parseXml(xml) {
    $("#main").html("<div id='box'><div id='title'>Latest from gulfnews.com</div>");
    $(xml).find("item").each(function(index) {
      if (index < 5) {
        $("#box").append("<div class='article'><span class='title'><a target='_blank' href='"+$(this).find("link").text()+"'>"+$(this).find("title").text()+"</a></span><h2>"+$(this).find("title").text()+"</h2></div>");
      }
    });  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea how I can 'show more'? and then display the others? I still want the first 5 to show.. I just want to show more underneath

Comment: @CharlotteOswald Could store `xml` response in variable available outside of `$.ajax()` scope , adjust `parseXml` function to begin `index` at `.length` of `.article` elements already in `DOM` , `:gt()` selector at `$(xml).find("item:gt("+$(".article").length+")")` ?

Comment: I'm really new to jQuery.. and that sounds really complicated.. I really need to get it done though !!!